# Session protection protect copying and pasting user identity cookie

Tags: c#, session-cookies

I logged in as user 1. and user2 in another browser. I have a user identity session value in cookie. when i copy user1 cookie value and paste it in user2 cookie value  user 2 got changed to user1 . How to prevent this?

Comment: You can't easily stop this. The session value **is** the identity. The main defense is to use https to avoid man in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot prevent exactly this behaviour. That means if someone gets a token to represent a user (a cookie in your case) then he can represent that user. This is called session-hijacking. Think of it as someone finding a key to another house, it's not much preventing that person from entering the house even though it's not his.

It is possible to do some workarounds that big sites like google do: check if it's a new location or a new computer and ask for additional validation for example, but it's probably not a simple feature.

Otherwise you need to protect your tokens as best as you can to prevent them being accessible in an easy way, like suggested in comments by using TLS, having HTTP-olny cookie that cannot be read by javascript, etc, ensuring proper logout that will delete the cookie and so on.